# How can i remove “addDisposableTo” when i used RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

when i use RxSwift, i must write many many addDisposableTo, how can i remove it?

```
usernameTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
            .bindTo(viewModel.username)
            .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    passwordTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .bindTo(viewModel.password)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    repeatPasswordTextField.rx.text.orEmpty
        .bindTo(viewModel.repeatPassword)
        .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: But you have to use it. When you subscribe, you make a "subscription" which you should unsubscribe from when you don’t need it anymore (`subscribe`, `bindTo` methods return a “subscription” called disposable) - it’s all about ownership. You can call `dispose` to returned disposables manually, or you can rely on a DisposeBag which will call `dispose` for all inner added subscriptions in its deinit method - which is much nicer then manage them manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by [Nimble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4374155/nimble), you have to do it; otherwise you will most certainly leak memory. The subscribe/unsubscribe couple at work relies on the same principle as native Swift Notification Center/KVO observers: if you open a "channel", you have to "close" it.

The middle ground here is to use [NSObject-Rx](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/NSObject-Rx) (by [Ash Furrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/516359/ash-furrow)) that prevents you from creating a dispose bag everywhere you `import RxSwift` in an `NSObject` subclass: simply call `.disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)`.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a code snippet in XCode for the subscription code and so its very handy that I don't have to type it in every time

I'm afraid since the dispose bag is a property that you tie to the object that is subscribing there is not much you can save in terms of boiler plate code.

May be you could write a convinience wrapper but still is it worth it? In my opinion XCode snippets works just fine